Displaying information on the site when using many-to-many relationships
I have two tables, categories and posts, and I have an intermediate table called category_post
I want to list the articles related to each category and show them on the site, for example, the category of agriculture, meteorology, nutrition, etc.
How can I show them in a many-to-many relationship, what query should I use?
For example, I show all the sections of the article, I want to show the category using the pivot table.
A news may have three categories
Can you guide me how to do it?
I used the following query, but it does not give me the answer I want
For example, I want to display the names of the categories inside the site
But through the pivot table, it only returns numbers, for example, number 1, number 2, but I want you to give me the name of the category
$posts = Post::with(['categories' => function ($query) use ($category){
 $query->where('name', $category);
 }])->get();

